# Reading from .txt file and writing to .txt file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Input_Output

Implicit none

Integer::i
Real::R_sn,X_sn,G_sn,B_sn

Open(Unit=2,File='Input.txt',Status='Unknown')

    Read(2,'(4(1x,En8.2))')R_sn,X_sn,G_sn,B_sn

Close(Unit=2,Status='Keep')

Open(Unit=4,File='Ouput.txt',Status='Unknown')

  Write(4,'(4(1x,En8.2))')R_sn,X_sn,G_sn,B_sn

Close(Unit=4,Status='Keep')

End Program Input_Output
```

The content of file `Input.txt` is:

`2.09E-01 1.17E-01 0.00E-00 1.16E-04`

The content of file `Output.txt` is:

`******** ******** 0.00E+00 ********`

My intention with this code is to read some numbers from file and afther that I want to write that numbers in other file in form from file which was used for reading. 
What is wrong with writing in `Output.txt` file?

Comment: Too short field (too few characters) in the descriptors. Just use `(*,*)` or more characters. Many duplicates around, cannot search for them from my phone.

Comment: I want to write numbers in En8.2 form to the  `Outpu.txt`. With using (*,*) I got numbers in f descriptor form

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `ES` data descriptor, which writes output in 'scientific notation`. This means a single leading digit before the decimal.

```
write(*,"(4(1x,es8.2))" R_sn, X_sn, G_sn, B_sn
!! output: 2.09E-01 1.17E-01 0.00E+00 1.16E-04
```

On the other hand, for `EN`, or 'engineering notation', you are writing (up to) 3 leading digits before the decimal. So you would need to expand the output field (suggested by @VladimirF):

```
write(*,"(4(1x,en10.2))" R_sn, X_sn, G_sn, B_sn
!! output: 209.00E-03 117.00E-03   0.00E+00 116.00E-06
```